# WordPress Contact form 7 not working with PHP 7.2 in Xampp

Tags: php, wordpress, contact-form-7

I have WordPress Version 5.3.2 with default theme Twenty Twenty and PHP version 7.2.24,then form is not submitted it shows error "There was an error trying to send your message. please try again later" with Red border.

Same It was working fine with PHP Vesrion 5.3.1

Comment: Hi, welcome to Stack Overflow. Do you have mail setup propertly with XAMPP? This could be a plethora of reasons.. check your error logs to find out. We are not here to do all this for you.

Comment: @GBWDev: No error log found and same was working with other PHP Vesrion 5.3.1

Answer (score 0):

Same issue happen with me with php 7.2 and Contact form 7 latest vesrion Wordpress.